# Getting Style builtin count without using forloop?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to get a total count of the builtin styles without having to use a for loop. Since I can get a count of all the (builtin and userdefined) with one statement, I thought the same could be done i.e for builtin ones by themselves. However, I'm running into either compile time or run time errors events though I'm imitating what a for loop specifies but trying to focus on the builtin ones only. I know that there is no way to tell the Style count property via a parameter such as .Styles(builtin).Count to give me the count for builtin styles vs. all of them .Styles.count. The VBA code below has the statements causing problems commented out so that the last debug statement will give me a number.   Is there anyway to do this or am I stuck with a for loop and a variable that keeps track of the count? I'm using the VBA code from doctools.com and the one at Microsoft website in the weblink below. Although the If statement has nothing in it for now (the future builtin count statement), I'm first trying to get it to compile and run first before trying to figure out the needed count statement for builtin styles only and not calling a sub that uses for loops.

Also the Set or no Set statement is trying to get the first Ostyle "in the" set of styles so that the if condition can at least test the first one. This would be like running the for loop one time. I think what I'm doing is trying to make it for the whole set and not just one of them. That's while VBA may be giving me the errors I'm getting. However, I don't know what I'm doing wrong to tell it only the first one in the set of styles.

```
Sub StylesBuiltin()
 
 ' Microsofts Example of built-in
 ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.style.builtin
 
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim oDocs As Word.Documents
Dim oStyle As Word.Style

'Set oStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles  ' Doesn't work with the set statement or without it....
'        If oStyle.BuiltIn = True Then
'        End If

Set oDoc = ActiveDocument

        Debug.Print "No of builtin & user-defined styles in doc" & oDoc.Styles.Count
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you want this number? You can probably ask Lene Fredborg directly about code found on doctools. ---- You are setting oStyle as a single style, rather than the collection then trying to set it to be the collection. You could do Set oStyle = Activedocument.Styles(1) and it will not throw an error. Don't know that it will help you, though.

Comment: I have already pointed you to the documentation on the names and numbers (hence counts) of the built-in Styles in different Word versions. Accordingly, you need only test the Word version to know how many built-in Styles it has.

Comment: I am in the process of learning how to get at the data I want. Since examples show for loops to process the data, I wanted to flatten this out to one thing at a time. Once I understand how to do it one at a time, one can roll it up into multiple data. Your solution fixed my compile/runtime problem. I was desperately defining different ways not understanding it in trying to get it to work.  See my attached answer using your fix. It now counts too each style type too by using the For i=1 to count instead of the For Each xx in collection set.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim oStyle As Word.Style

'Set oStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles
```

It should be pretty obvious to you why that statement is doomed to failure. You have declared `oStyle` as a `Word.Style` (singular) and then tried to set it to equal `ActiveDocument.Styles` (plural) which is the collection of all the styles in the document.

What you need is a `For Each` loop, which is exactly what the example in the Help article you quoted gives you. You just need to edit it very slightly for your purpose:

```
Dim styleLoop As Style
Dim builtInStylesCounter as Long
 
For Each styleLoop in ActiveDocument.Styles 
 If styleLoop.BuiltIn = True Then builtInStylesCounter = builtInStylesCounter + 1
Next styleLoop
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I don't know the proper way to tell it syntactically yet. Its experimenting doing things different ways to get a better understanding. Most examples use for loops, and I wanted to do it without them first.

Answer (score -1):

The code below includes the answer to fix a problem for compile/runtime. The first part allows one to access one style name at a time. Using this, a For i=1 To Count is used along with the builtin tests to tabulate builtin and non-built style names as an alternative to doing it with the For Each .. in the data collection set.  In the end, the only way is via a for loop since a call to the Object model doesn't give it except for the overall count. One could make i.e. 472 some calls and test for each style while counting them which would eliminate the for loop.. :)

```
Sub StylesBuiltin()
 
 ' Microsofts Example of built-in
 ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.style.builtin
 
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim oDocs As Word.Documents
Dim oStyle As Word.Style
Dim index As Long
Dim numBuiltin, numUserDefined As Long

Set oDoc = ActiveDocument

index = 3 ' For a user-defined style name I have "Appendix 1" that when sorted in the styles list is at index=3
      ' the expected test result is "Is not in builtin styles"

       ' This allows one to eventually define a function/subroutine that can
       ' test a Style Name one at a time.
       ' I.e. a function isBuiltin(index:=3)   would return true/false
       '  or i.e.   isBuiltin("Appendix 1")   would return true/false


' Set oStyle = oDoc.Styles("Appendix 1")        
Set oStyle = oDoc.Styles(index)
       If oStyle.BuiltIn = True Then
            Debug.Print "Index " & index & " Is builtin styles"
       Else
            Debug.Print "Index " & index & " Is not in built styles"
        End If


Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
        ' This tells me how many builtin and user-defined styles I currently have to work
        ' with in the opened document. It isn't the number of styles that were used in the opened document.
        
        Debug.Print "No of builtin & user-defined styles doc " & oDoc.Styles.Count
        
        ' Since there is no way to get either the built-in or user-defined styles using these as a constraint
        ' such as .Styles(builtin).Count or .Styles.Count(builtin) since it doesn't exist, one has to write
        ' the routines to do this.  Doctools.com/MSoft shows how to do it by looping thru the objects using
        ' For Each  ... In the collection set.  Another way is the For i=1 To .Styles.Count that tests
        ' the builtin true/false condition to count the number of values.
        
        For index = 1 To oDoc.Styles.Count
          Set oStyle = oDoc.Styles(index)
          If oStyle.BuiltIn = True Then
            numBuiltin = numBuiltin + 1
          ElseIf oStyle.BuiltIn <> True Then
            numUserDefined = numUserDefined + 1
          End If
          Next index
        
          Debug.Print " No of built-in styles " & numBuiltin
          Debug.Print " No of user-defined styles " & numUserDefined
          
End Sub
```

Comment: I won’t waste time explaining to you how inefficient your code is as you appear determined to tread your own path and ignore advice offered to you by people with vastly more experience.

Comment: I'm not questioning your experience. I'm just in the process of learning VBA since I'm a beginner and experimenting to understand how to write VBA code. With time I'll get better. Also, I don't dont completely understand how to manipulate objects yet.